# abs of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Which is the easy way of getting the abs of an array in php? It has to be a better way. This works, but in multidimensional array it has some limitations

```
function make_abs($numbers) {
 $abs_array = array();

 foreach($numbers as $key=>$value)
   $abs_array[$key] = abs($value);

 return $abs_array;
}
```

Comment: you could use `array_walk`, but that code isn't *that* complicated.

Comment: i was thinking at using something as a reference &, but i don;t know how to use it

Comment: A reference approach would simply be: foreach($numbers as &$value) $value = abs($value);  However, array_walk is more suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variant using references (this does not solve your recursion problem, just FYI):

```
function make_abs(&$numbers)
{
    foreach($numbers as &$value)
        $value = abs($value)
    ;
}
```

For the recursion problem, you need to step into each array:

```
function make_abs(&$numbers)
{
    foreach($numbers as &$value)
        is_array($value) ? make_abs($value) : $value = abs($value)
    ;
}
```

PHP itself has a somewhat handy function for that, [`array_walk_recursive`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive). The problem with that function is, it expects the callback to have two parameters, value (by reference) and key. Many PHP functions do not fit those requirements. You can work around that by creating yourself a helper function to use any function that only takes one parameter and returns the modified value. You pass the function as with [`array_map`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_map):

```
function array_walk_recursive_map(array &$array, $callback)
{
    $byRef = function(&$item, $key) use ($callback)
    {
        $item = $callback($item);
    };
    array_walk_recursive($array, $byRef);
}

# Usage:
array_walk_recursive_map($numbers, 'abs');
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Use a map function:

```
array_map("abs", $numbers)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 2):

You could do `array_walk_recursive($numbers, 'make_abs');`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

**Edit**

```
$numbers = array(1, 35, 107);

function make_abs(&$item,$key) { // use with reference
    $item = abs($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($numbers, 'make_abs');
```

This example works with multidimensional arrays.